# Adding user input names to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to ask the user for 2 inputs, first name and last name, return a greeting and store the names in a Dictionary with the Keys being 'FName' and 'LName'

The following stores the greeting fine....

```
def name():
    d = {}
    x = input('Please enter your first name: ')
    y = input('Please enter your last name: ')
    d = {}
    d[x] = y

    print("Hello", x, y)
    print(d)

name()
```

but I am not sure how to get the key/values in the dictionary properly.  Right now it stores the equivalent of:

```
{'Joe': 'Smith'}
```

I know I need to reformat the following line different I am just not sure how to approach it...

```
d[x] = y
```

Comment: Now you are storing the key first name with value last name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to manually set the keys you are storing against

```
d['FName'] = x
d['LName'] = y
```

Or more simply

```
d = {
    'FName': x,
    'LName': y
}
```

Comment: ahh I see now what he is trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example:

```
def name():
    d = {}
    qs = dict(Fname='first name', Lname='last name')
    for k,v in qs.items():
        d[k] = input('Please enter your {}: '.format(v))
    return d

name()
```

Comment: Thanks that is a cool way to set it up.  Dumb question, how can I print/see the dictionary results after it runs?  I tried adding print(qs) and print(d).  Neither of them worked...

Comment: @JD2775 those are local variables, you would need to return them. Try printing inside the function

Comment: ah, got it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.  Sorry.

```
d['Fname'] = x
d['Lname'] = y
```

Comment: if this is truly your desired solution, you can either accept this answer or delete the question. Good job figuring it out, by the way :)

Comment: Thanks, how do you delete a question? I think I may have others going forward that I realize are easy right after I ask them :)

Comment: Hey that's good too, whatever works :) Feel free to keep them, or https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42297/376870. Ah my mistake, you may not be able to delete it now "You can only delete it if you have non upvoted answers."